# How can I define a route differently if parameter is not integer

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am using Laravel 5 and working on my local.
I made a route with a parameter of {id} and another route with a specific name like so :

```
Route::get('contacts/{id}', 'ContactController@get_contact');
Route::get('contacts/new', 'ContactController@new_contact');
```

My problem here is that if I try to go at localhost/contacts/new it will automatically access to the get_contact method. I understand that I have made a {id} parameter but what if I want to call get_contact only if my parameter is an integer? If it is not, check if it's "new" and access to new_contact method. Then, if it's not an integer and not "new", error page 404.

How can I do that in Laravel 5?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Just add `->where('id', '[0-9]+')` to route where you want to accept number-only parameter:

```php
Route::get('contacts/{id}', 'ContactController@get_contact')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
Route::get('contacts/new', 'ContactController@new_contact');
```

Read more: http://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-parameters

Comment: Great!!! I probably jumped hover in their documentation. Thanks a lot! I will accept your answer in 10 minutes :)

Comment: What if the value of the number exceeds an int?

Answer (score 16):

Although the accepted answer is perfectly fine, usually a parameter is used more than once and thus you might want to use a DRY approach by defining a pattern in your `boot` function in the `RouteServiceProvider.php` file located under `app/Providers`
(Laravel 5.3 and onwards):

```
 /**
 * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Route::pattern('id', '[0-9]+');

    parent::boot();
}
```

This way, whereever you use your `{id}` parameter the constraints apply.

Comment: Nice answer, but is this work with the resource route? `Route::resource` ?

Answer (score 15):

A simple solution would be to use an explicit approach.

```
Route::get('contacts/{id:[0-9]+}', 'ContactController@get_contact');
Route::get('contacts/new', 'ContactController@new_contact');
```

Comment: this doesn't work in Laravel 5.8, showing "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT, PATCH." error....

Comment: Do you have link to documentation for this? Did not work in Laravel 7

Answer (score 10):

There is also the possibility to just switch those around, because route file will go through all lines from top to bottom until it finds a valid route.

```
Route::get('contacts/new', 'ContactController@new_contact');
Route::get('contacts/{id}', 'ContactController@get_contact');
```

If you want to restrict that route to pure numbers, the marked solution is correct though.

Just adding it here, I know it is quite old ;)

Comment: I found this to work more reliably even with Laravel 10. 
The where() seemed not to work if you reverse the route position to start with the one with id

Answer (score 0):

Create your own request and add validation rule. Also, use this request as an argument for controller method

```
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules(Request $request)
{
    return [
        'id' => 'required|integer'
    ];
}

/**
 * @return array
 */
public function validationData()
{
    return array_replace_recursive(
        $this->all(),
        $this->route()->parameters()
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just change the order of lines

```
Route::get('contacts/new', 'ContactController@new_contact');
Route::get('contacts/{id}', 'ContactController@get_contact');
```

it will work!

Comment: This would work, but it's not what the OP actually asked for. Imagine that the developer in this case wants to leave (or rather might have to leave) the lines in the order that they are. This solves the problem, but is not the best solution