# Routes are conflicting in Laravel framework php

Tags: php, laravel, api

I have already 
a/{id}
api

Now I want
a/b

But it is not hitting a/b, it is hitting a/{id} and taking b as {id}

How can I create a/b assuming I am not allowed to change a/{id}?

Framework Laravel.

```js
$apiRoutes = [
        // Dev routes
        'get_a_by_id' => ['get',      'a/{id}','AController@getA'],

        // App routes
        'fetch_all_b'                                  => ['get','a/b', 'BController@getB'],
        ]
```

This is my code route.php
Even reordering also doesn't work.

Comment: Hi Ranjith. Share your current code so that we can help from what we see. Remember StackOverflow is about helping you fix your code rather than writing code for you.

Comment: @Ranjith, It's better to work on the existing code to avoid so many confusions. Please post the code too.

Comment: Please share the route definition. Is `b` always static? Is `id` always numeric?

Comment: @NicoHaase b is always static and id can be alphanumeric not just numeric

Comment: Then have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30414860/how-can-i-define-a-route-differently-if-parameter-is-not-integer

Comment: @NicoHaase it works only if id is numeric, in my case it is alphanumeric

Comment: ...well, that linked question has an answer for that too: define the static route before the dynamic. And then hope that there is no case that `id == b`

Comment: @NicoHaase yes it works If I directly create using route, but in my case I am storing all apis in an array. For this even putting static api at first doesn't work either.

Comment: @NicoHaase it is working, I forgot to rearrange in one more array that is what actually calling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is

First place `a/b` above `a/{id}` and add `->where(['id' => '[0-9]+');` this will make sure that the route `a/{id}` will trigger only if there is numeric value.

You can change regex based on your needs.

```
Route::get('a/b', function () {
    //code
});

Route::get('a/{id}', function ($id) {
    //code
})->where(['id' => '[0-9]+');
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends in which order you define them, you need to first create the specific route `a/b` then below the wildcard one.

```
Route::get('a/b', function () {
    dd('testing b');
});

Route::get('a/{id}', function ($id) {
    dd('testing', $id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is to define `a/b` before `a/{id}`

Here's my example:

```
Route::get('/v1/smsportal/search/{type?}/{search?}', 'SMSPortals@search');
Route::get('/v1/smsportal/{id?}', 'SMSPortals@get');
Route::post('/v1/smsportal', 'SMSPortals@save');
Route::post('/v1/smsportal/{id?}', 'SMSPortals@update');
Route::delete('/v1/smsportal/{id?}', 'SMSPortals@delete');
```

`/v1/smsportal/search` will be called before `/v1/smspotal/{id}` if I call for `search`.