# Laravel Routing Issue when change integer into string

Tags: laravel, routes

The La ravel project routing page has

```
    Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function (){
      Route::get('user/{user_code}', 'UserController@show');
    });
```

The `UserController` show function is

```
    public function show($user_code)
    {
        echo "hi";
    }
```

It is working if the `user_code` is integer.
    And not working if it is string , for example : user/L123

Redirecting to a page with message

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Can you help me please?

Comment: This post may help you:) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30414860/how-can-i-define-a-route-differently-if-parameter-is-not-integer

Comment: its should be working fine, the issue will be something other.

Comment: There is no problem, this is working fine